# Is this a typo, or is the natural symbol normally omitted here?

Tags: theory, chords

The song is in D major, but the Bb13 (#11) chord has no natural in front of the C. Since a C# would give a #9, I first thought this was a typo. But then I wondered if this is some kind of convention, in which the chord notation takes precedence over the key signature.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the D major is correctly notated with two sharps in the key signature, then this is simply a misprint. There should be a natural before the 'C'.

Alternatively (but unlikely): the C-sharp is correct and the chord symbol is wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear my first hunch was right. Plus, the C-sharp here sounds a little off.

Comment: @DropShadow C# is only a theoretical possibility, I agree it doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 1):

The notes which constitute a 13 chord are 1, 3, 5, ♭7, 9, 11 and 13. On a normal B♭13 chord they translate as B♭ (R), D(3), F(5), A♭(flat7), C(9), E♭(11) and G(13). Often 5 is omitted, and 9 and 11 can also be. Particularly on guitar - where there's just no physical way to play all the notes.

Here, on the stave, there's the B♭ and A♭ in bass. Treble has C♯,D, E, and G.

Because it's a ♯11, E♮ is fine - that's o.k. As is the G - the 13.

So, the query is the 9th - the C. There is a C♯ tied over from the previous bar, but that doesn't matter, it ends where the tie ends. But any other C in the bar resumes its sharp - from the key signature. Which makes the lowest note shown in the treble clef C♯. The chord needs M9 to make up the chord shown - so that C will need to be shown as C♮.